# Check Session timeout on invoking constructor of a controller in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I'am handling session expiry in my MVC 4 application using the following method:

step 1: created the following class:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class SessionExpireFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

         string controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName.ToLower();
         string actonName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName.ToLower();
         if (!(controllerName.Contains("account")||(controllerName.Contains("home") && actonName.Contains("index"))))
         {

             // If the browser session or authentication session has expired...
             if (SessionManager.Instance["PlatformId"] == null || !filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
             {
                 if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                 {

                     filterContext.Result = new JsonResult { Data = "_Logon_" };
                 }
                 else
                 {

                     filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                         new RouteValueDictionary {
                    { "Controller", "Home" },
                    { "Action", "TimeoutRedirect" }
            });
                 }
             }
         }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

step 2: Added it to RegisterGlobalFilters as follows:

```
    filters.Add(new SessionExpireFilterAttribute());
```

I tested this while session is alive and its working fine- while executing each action it is checking whether session is active. But the problem is I'am initializing some objects in constructor using session values as follows:

```
     public class DashboardController : BaseController
{
    private DashboardService dashboardService;


    public DashboardController()
    {

        dashboardService = new DashboardService(this.DbContext, (int)SessionManager.Instance["PlatformId"]);

    }
 }
```

When session times out obviously null reference exception is thrown at

```
        dashboardService = new DashboardService(this.DbContext, (int)SessionManager.Instance["PlatformId"])
```

before session expiry check is made. I cannot move all these initializations to every actions because it is hectic-I already have a lot of action methods.

So is there any way to check session time out when Constructor method is invoked? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

What I am doing is Checking for the Session in application's Application_AcquireRequestState method (Global.asax)

something like this

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (HttpContext.Current.Handler is IRequiresSessionState)
     {
         var usrobj = HttpContext.Current.Session["User"];
         if(usrobj == null)
         {
             Response.Redirect("~/Login/Index");
         }
     }
}
```

I don't know if you want something along the same lines.

Comment: Thanks for the response.Is there a way to know which controller and action method is being called inside this Application_AcquireRequestState mathod?

Comment: You cannot call the controller or any action method in Global.asax, What do you want to achieve with that?

Comment: I dont want to call controller or action method from within global.asax, I just want to check which action is being called because only for actions other than Index in Account controller I want to check for session expiry.

Comment: I believe you can check which Controller / Action is being called by having this: string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.ToString();